# Parsing individual sentences from a paragraph

Tags: scala, parsing, nlp

I'm trying to build a parser that can turn a paragraph into a list of sentences, but I'm running into a major problem. So I'm using the stanford parser to pull out the sentences intelligently, but the issue is that the parser only stores the list of tokens, rather than the sentence itself. This can become very problematic if my client wants the text EXACTLY as it showed up before (including any spacing that was there before.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can get around this problem?

```
def prepSentenceStrings(text: String): List[String] = {
     val mod = text.replace("Sr.", "Sr") // deals with an edge case
     val doc = new DocumentPreprocessor(new StringReader(mod))
     doc.map(x => reconfigureSentence(Sentence.listToString(x))).toList}


def reconfigureSentence(text:String) :String = {
    text.replace(" .", ".").replace(" ,",",").replace(" !", "!").replace("( ","(").replace("< ", "<").replace(" )", ")")
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem of performing sentence splitting with Stanford NLP is that it first tokenizes the whole paragraph and removes all whitespace characters in the process. As far as I know, there is no way to reconstruct them and there is always the risk that you end up with a sentence that has slightly been altered.

Do you have to use Scala for your task? There are already very good sentence splitting solutions like the [Sentence Segmentation Tool](http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/tools_view/2) which  is implemented in Perl. I have used this tool a few times and was very content with the output. Maybe you can call it from your Scala program and then process the result?

[Here](http://tech.grammarly.com/blog/posts/How-to-Split-Sentences.html) you find an overview about different sentence splitters and how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Epic library](http://fukaeri:epic%20dlwh%20(master)$%20java%20-Xmx8g%20-cp%20target/scala-2.11/epic-assembly-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar%20epic.preprocess.SegmentSentences%20fukaeri:epic%20dlwh%20(master)$%20vi%20qq.txt%20fukaeri:epic%20dlwh%20(master)$%20cat%20qq.txt%20I'm%20trying%20to%20build%20a%20parser%20that%20can%20turn%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20paragraph%20into%20a%20list%20of%20sentences,%20but%20I'm%20running%20into%20a%20major%20problem.%20So%20I'm%20using%20the%20stanford%20parser%20to%20pull%20out%20the%20sentences%20intelligently,%20but%20the%20issue%20is%20that%20the%20parser%20only%20stores%20the%20list%20of%20tokens,%20rather%20than%20the%20sentence%20itself.%20This%20can%20become%20very%20problematic%20if%20my%20client%20wants%20the%20text%20EXACTLY%20as%20it%20showed%20up%20before%20(including%20any%20spacing%20that%20was%20there%20before.%20fukaeri:epic%20dlwh%20(master)$%20java%20-Xmx8g%20-cp%20target/scala-2.11/epic-assembly-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar%20epic.preprocess.SegmentSentences%20%3C%20qq.txt%20I'm%20trying%20to%20build%20a%20parser%20that%20can%20turn%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20paragraph%20into%20a%20list%20of%20sentences,%20but%20I'm%20running%20into%20a%20major%20problem.%20So%20I'm%20using%20the%20stanford%20parser%20to%20pull%20out%20the%20sentences%20intelligently,%20but%20the%20issue%20is%20that%20the%20parser%20only%20stores%20the%20list%20of%20tokens,%20rather%20than%20the%20sentence%20itself.%20This%20can%20become%20very%20problematic%20if%20my%20client%20wants%20the%20text%20EXACTLY%20as%20it%20showed%20up%20before%20(including%20any%20spacing%20that%20was%20there%20before.)'s [SentenceSegmenter](https://github.com/dlwh/epic/blob/7322d3eac388ce63c260dd2254943393ee254c8a/src/main/scala/epic/preprocess/SentenceSegmenter.scala), which also comes with a main-method for convenience. Otherwise, it just takes a string and returns an `IndexedSeq[String]`, one for each sentence. Whitespace is preserved. If you want char-offsets, you can look at Epic's Slab data structure, which can be used for that purpose.

```
fukaeri:epic dlwh (master)$ java -Xmx8g -cp target/scala-2.11/epic-assembly-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar epic.preprocess.SegmentSentences
fukaeri:epic dlwh (master)$ vi qq.txt
fukaeri:epic dlwh (master)$ cat qq.txt
I'm trying to build a parser that can turn a          paragraph into a list of sentences, but I'm running into a major problem. So I'm using the stanford parser to pull out the sentences intelligently, but the issue is that the parser only stores the list of tokens, rather than the sentence itself. This can become very problematic if my client wants the text EXACTLY as it showed up before (including any spacing that was there before.
fukaeri:epic dlwh (master)$ java -Xmx8g -cp target/scala-2.11/epic-assembly-0.4-SNAPSHOT.jar epic.preprocess.SegmentSentences < qq.txt
I'm trying to build a parser that can turn a          paragraph into a list of sentences, but I'm running into a major problem.
So I'm using the stanford parser to pull out the sentences intelligently, but the issue is that the parser only stores the list of tokens, rather than the sentence itself.
This can become very problematic if my client wants the text EXACTLY as it showed up before (including any spacing that was there before.
```